# While printing boundary size of object in an image getting error in python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I am getting an error while running the below code. Code is to determine the boundary size in an image which is 2-d square having 4 squares inside and separated by black boundary which denotes 0 in array. Here is the code below:

```
from matplotlib import colors as Col
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import cv2
a1 = []
a2 = []
img = cv2.imread('ColorPickinChooser_256px.png',0)
plt.imshow(img)
height, width = img.shape
print(height, width)
pix = np.array(img)
print(pix)
for row in pix:
    if pix[row] == 0:
        a1.append(pix[row])
    bound_size = len(a1)
    for col in pix:
        if pix[col] == 0:
            a2.append(pix[col])
        bound_size_col = len(a2)

print('Boundary size: ', bound_size)
print('Boundary size in col: ', bound_size_col)
```

This is the error I am getting:
  File "C:/Users/500066016/.spyder-py3/image_boundary.py", line 14, in 
    if pix[row] == 0:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Answer (score 0):

You're behaving pix[row] as a scalar value while this is not an single value,
in line 14 use :

```
if not pix[row].any():
# Rest of your code
```

this line of code ensures that none of the elements are any thing except zero in that row

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind `pix` is an array of two dimensions (rows and columns). Passing `if pix[row] == 0:` does not make sense.

What you mean to imply is:

```
for row in pix[1]:
    if row == 0:
```

the same goes for the columns:

```
for col in pix[0]:
    if col == 0:
```

Now proceed with the rest of your code.

Comment: Thanks, got it. Working now